# Java method to get separator from user

Tags: java, separator

I'm writing this method in my program that parses text files to XML. The user provides the separator of the file. The file might be separated by comma, colon, tab, or pipe. The method below works for comma but not the other 3. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
public static String getSeparator(String separator) {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter the separator type (commas, Colons, Tabs, Pipes)");
        separator = userInput.nextLine();
    } while (!separator.equals(",") || separator.equals(":") || separator.equals("   ") || separator.equals("|"));

    return separator;
}
```

Comment: You are only using a ! (not equals) for the comma and not for any of the other separators. Either add ! or use parenthesis.

Comment: Your logical NOT ("`!`") applies to the first condition only. You need parentheses.

Comment: `} while (!separator.matches(",|:|\\t|\\|"));`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a parentheses around the whole condition.

```
while (!(separator.equals(",") || separator.equals(":") || separator.equals("   ") || separator.equals("|")));
```

Better way is to define an String array of the seperators:

```
String[] seperators = new String[] {",",":"," ","|"};
```

And then check if it is in list:

```
} while (!Arrays.asList(seperators).contains(seperator));
```

Comment: Thanks, Adding the not operator to all conditions worked.